# Usage of cookie-parser with passport.js still needed?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, passport.js

Can not find any info (on `passport.js` site) about general `passport.js` instalation and declaration in `node.js`.
In the tutorials I always see `express session` middleware and `cookie-parser` stated as required for `passport`, yet `session` docs (https://github.com/expressjs/session) notes:

'Since version 1.5.0, the cookie-parser middleware no longer needs to be used for this module to work. This module now directly reads and writes cookies on req/res. Using cookie-parser may result in issues if the secret is not the same between this module and cookie-parser.'

So do I need to use `session` & `cookie-parser` for `passport` for some reasons, or I can use only `session`, am I need to tweak something then?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, passport itself does not require cookie-parser middleware.  If you want session-persistent authentication then you'll need the express-session middleware, which *used* to require cookie-parser, but modern versions of express no longer have this requirement (the current version of express-session reads and writes cookies directly).

Comment: Haha, that was an oooold question, but yeah, answer is perfectly correct, thanks.

Comment: Indeed.  I came looking for the same information and found that nobody had answered your question yet so I figured I'd answer it for the next person that comes looking.  By the way, the docs for passport really need to be updated: many of the examples won't work with the latest version of Express.

Comment: and glad you did! @Wrecks